# Is there a += in Smalltalk? Or anything similar?

Tags: smalltalk

E.g., would like to do stuff like `myVal += theAmount` - is there anything similar to this in smalltalk? I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is, but it is a regular message send, not a special assignment statement.

In Squeak, there is for example FloatArray>>+=, which adds another array's elements to the receiver's elements:

```
| f |
f := #(1 2 3) asFloatArray.
f += #(4 5 6).
f
==> a FloatArray(5.0 7.0 9.0)
```

What's important is that f refers to the same object before and after receiving the += message. Only its contents changes. You can implement += for your own classes in a similar way.

What you can not do (*) is using += to replace the value of a variable, like in other languages. It is just a regular message send and the receiving object might do something useful with it.

(*) without hacking the compiler. If you're insistent you can do anything, but in general it is not a Good Idea to do so.

Answer (score 7):

No. Everything happens with message sends, so it's not possible to define an operation that assigns a new value to the left-hand side. Only assignments with := can do that.

Answer (score 4):

Theoretically there can be some sort of hacks. For example you can define class `NewNumber` with and store it's value in a `value` instance variable. Now you can define

```
+= increment
    value := value + increment
```

:)

Or even unary message

```
increment
    value := value + 1
```

that will act as ++. But all the magic with Numbers is done with a help of primitives (functions on the VM side that can work with memory directly. It's possible to define a primitive that will modify the state of a number and then call it in += method, but adding new primitives sucks and current style (where you always use a return value) is quite nice to be honest.

Comment: And one of the really nice things about Numbers is that they are referentially transparent. You don't edit the state of a Number, but get a new Number with the desired state change.

Answer (score 0):

Lengthy discussion here where it shows that instVars are not like regular objects: http://computer-programming-forum.com/3-smalltalk/6f56ed2338c3b0fa.htm

Slots in Pharo5+ could do something about this...